# How to remove already enqueued messages in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How to remove already enqueued messages in joomla 2.5?
Thanks in advance!

I tried

```
$jAp = JFactory::getApplication();
$messagesexist = $jAp->getMessageQueue();
```

But the above code is showing all the enqued messages.
From that I want to remove particular message.

Comment: A enqueue message from what? A component? If so, which component? What have you already tried?

Comment: yes it is from component

Comment: Try looking in the controller for that specific view of the component. You will most likely see something like: `$message = JText::_('LANG_STRING');` followed by `$this->setRedirect($url, $message, $messageType);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
                $session = JFactory::getSession();
                $sessionQueue = $session->get('application.queue');
                if (count($sessionQueue)) {
                        $session->set('application.queue', null);
                }
```

Hope its works..

Answer (score 1):

To remove a particular message you will have to work through the `array` returned by `getMessageQueue()`.

So something like this:

```
// Get the message queue
$messages = JFactory::getApplication()->getMessageQueue();

// If we have messages
if (is_array($messages) && count($messages))
{
    // Check each message for the one we want
    foreach ($messages as $message)
    {
        // do your checks here
    }
}
```